# Laravel echo listenForWhisper not working with laravel-websockets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-websockets

I'm trying to create a room where we will broadcast changes made to a document.

Currently, I have the following code:

```js
const channel = window.Echo.private('some-channel');


setInterval(() => {
  channel.whisper('something', { payload: 'foo' });
}, 1000);

window.Echo.private('some-channel').listenForWhisper('something', (e) => {
  console.log('someone whispered');
  console.log(e);
  console.log('-------');
})
```

With the full payload being:

```json
{"event":"client-something","data":{"payload":"foo"},"channel":"private-some-channel"}
```

I login into my application from two different browsers (Chrome and Chrome in incognito mode) but I do not see any `console.log` in my browser's console.

I can see the messages are being sent:

[image]

I have enabled [enable_client_messages](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher#client-messages) in my `config/websockets.php` file:

```php
'apps' => [
  [
    'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
    'capacity' => null,
    'enable_client_messages' => true,
    'enable_statistics' => true,
  ],
],
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not being able to see the `console.log` in `user A` or `user B` browser consoles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the route authentication in `routes/channels.php`

```php
Broadcast::channel('some-channel', function ($user) {
    return $user;
});
```